# QGIS Random Points in Polygon PRESERVING Attribute Table?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, overlapping-features, point-in-polygon, random

I have a complicated shapefile of overlapping polygons. I need to generate random points inside each polygon, which is easily accomplished using Vector -> Research Tools -> Random Points Inside Polygons, but this obliterates the attribute table of the generated point shapefile which is not okay. Under more simple conditions, I could use NNJoin to rejoin the attributes, but because of the multiple overlapping polygons this is not acceptable as I cannot be sure the nearest polygon is actually the correct source of data. Can anyone suggest a method to generate a single random point in each polygon that has a 1:1 (ie., perfect) transfer of the attributes from the polygon to the random point, for each polygon?

Answer (score 3):

I've made a PR to support your requirement at https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/36479

You can take the file `RandomPointsPolygons.py` from the PR and replace the one on your machine with the same name (make a copy before, to be safe). Then, restart QGIS and it should do what you want.

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much for this! Does this mean it might eventually make its way into QGIS' native feature set?

Comment: It should if PR is accepted: waiting for QGIS devs feedback

Comment: Amazing. Thanks so much, Thomas. Open source GIS forever!

Comment: @MeanderPhotography Please accept this answer if it solves your problem.